# A cake where disputes are hard to solve

Tags: combinatorics

A 1-dimensional cake has to be divided among 3 people, marked A B and C. The cake has 7 parts. The values that each people assigns to each part are as follows :

- For person A: $30, 01, 28, 01, 28, 01, 01$ (total = 90)
- For person B: $29, 01, 20, 00, 10, 01, 29$ (total = 90)
- For person C: $01, 09, 20, 01, 20, 09, 30$ (total = 90)

This cake has the following interesting property: If any one of the people cuts the cake to three pieces that he thinks are of equal value (i.e. 30), then both other people want the same piece. I.e.:

- If A cuts, then he cuts after part #1 and after part #4, and both B and C prefer the third piece (which they value as 40 and 59).
- If B cuts, then he cuts after part #2 and after part #5, and both C and A prefer the second piece (which they value as 41 and 57).
- If C cuts, then he cuts after part #3 and after part #6, and both A and B prefer the first piece (which they value as 59 and 50).

MY QUESTION IS: Is it possible to find such a curious scenario for every number of people? I.e., is it possible to find, for every $n$, a cake which $n$ people value differently, such that, if any one person cuts the cake to $n$ pieces that he thinks are equal, then all other people *strongly* prefer the same piece?

NOTE: By "strongly prefer" I mean that they think they value this piece strictly more than the other pieces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{cccccc}
2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
2 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
2 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 \\
2 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: Much simpler than my own example. Thanks!

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi you're welcome :)